# How to disable a control in command field control in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to find a command field control in the gridview.

in a method not in the row data bound.

so far i have used this coding but i cant find the control.

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="True
                  HeaderText="Enter Leave"
                  EditImageUrl="~/IMAGES/edit-icon.gif">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

source code:

```
ImageButton edit = (ImageButton)EmployeeDetails.FindControl("Image");
edit.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: You should specify in what row you want to disable the imageButton.

Comment: do you really need to use CommandField or ItemTemplate is ok ? If it is, I can answer.

Comment: ya command feild only i want to diable the button in the column based on the condition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable column itself with,

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = false;
```

from code behind pages.

---

Or you can use ItemTemplate instead of CommandField,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="id" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And at code behind you can iterate through rows of GridView and disable each LinkButton.

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    LinkButton row = gvr.FindControl("id") as LinkButton;
    row.Enabled = false;
}
```

---

**First Edit :**

I tried my second solution and it works. However, make sure your `GridView` is filled before you use `foreach`. Otherwise, `GridView.Rows.Count` would probably be 0.

---

**Second Edit :**

This works for `CommandField` too. Replace 0 with the location of `CommandField` in your `GridView`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{        
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         e.Row.Cells[0].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i no need visible i need to disable

Comment: do you mean button should be visible but it should not be clickable ?

Comment: I don't think so. I searched a lot but could not find a solution for command field. If you want to do this in command field, you probably need to use DataBound or RowDataBound events.

Comment: k tell me how to handle in the row databound for the particular column

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try to hide controls at DataBound or RowDataBound event of GridView

protected void EmployeeDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ImageButton edit = (ImageButton)EmployeeDetails.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("Image");
        edit.Visible = false;  
        edit.Enabled = false; //OR use this line
}
```

particular column can be disabled in the following way

```
EmployeeDetails.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: he does not want to do that on any GridView event.

Comment: i want to diable that column itself

Comment: EmployeeDetails.Columns[0].Enabled this code will not at all work did u noticed enabled prperty will not come at all

Answer (score 1):

You miss to specify the row

Something like :

```
ImageButton edit = (ImageButton)EmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("Image");
edit.Enabled = false;
```

If you want to disable the column that contains the imageButton , you can do :

```
EmployeeDetails.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: coulmns i want to diable not visible

Comment: i need the particular column to be diabled not in the grid view row event

Comment: @KAJAH so you should disable all the controls in that column on DataBound

Comment: k send the code in the rowdatabound it self based on the condition

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I simply *disabled the view of the Column* in `BindData()` function.

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

This worked for me, since my first column was Edit column and I have to enable it for specific users only.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cast it as a DataControlFieldCell and then set Enabled to false.

Where: row.Controls[0] is your CommandField control

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in ManageDNXGridView.Rows)
{
    DataControlFieldCell editable = (DataControlFieldCell)row.Controls[0];
    editable.Enabled = false; 
}
```