# Remove Edit Option in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

My GridView is as follows

It has EmptyDatatemplate and Command Field

```
   <asp:GridView ID="AGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="2000px"   RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
           &nbsp;
       </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="80px" EditText="Edit">
         <ItemStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" />
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="AAddOn" />
         </asp:CommandField>
  </asp:GridView>
```

GridView Looks like(it has only 2 rows)

```
Name   Age  Country
A      10    NNN       Edit  
B      23    NNN       Edit
```

Now i dont need Edit Button to be displayed in first row.How can i do it.

Only 2 rows  will be displayed here.

```
Name   Age  Country
A      10    NNN         
B      23    NNN       Edit
```

Here header is count of Gridview Header cells and my edit is in last cell.
(My Gridview generated dynamically generated columns but has only 2 rows so i cannot take fixed column values hence used header count)

```
 Dim Header As Integer
 For counts = 0 To AGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count
  Header = counts
  Next
 Dim  edit as LinkButton  = DirectCast(AGridView.Rows(0).cell(header).FindControl("Edit"),LinkButton)
    edit.Visible = False
```

Error message for above is  Object reference not set to instance.Index is out of range.

Next I have tried inside AGridView_Rowdatabound as  but whole cell is disappearing .I need only  First row edit linkbutton visible to be false

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    e.Row.Cells(Header).Visible = False
End If
```

What am i missing here.I need only First row edit button visible to be false.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461302/conditionally-hide-commandfield-or-buttonfield-in-gridview.

Comment: Hi i looked into the solution but i dont have boundfields..Since my gridview shows only 2 rows ,how can i  do this in gridview rowdatabound.I mean like row(1) button visible should be false likewise..

Comment: I don't think it matters. The idea in the accepted answer there is to replace CommandField (which you do have) with ItemTemplate where you can create Edit command button for which you can conditionally set the Visible property. Alternativelly you can try the proposed solution at the bottom of the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7188143/4955259. It seems to use the CommandField and the RowDataBound event handler instead.

Comment: Hi i have tried your link but i cannot get solution..I have edited my question of what have i tried..I guess iam missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comment section of the question, assuming that you want to disable Edit button only for the first data row and that the button is in the 4th column, I suggest trying this:

Add the `OnRowDataBound` declaration to the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="AGridView" ... OnRowDataBound="AGridView_RowDataBound">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

Add `RowDataBound` event handler to the code behind file:

```
Protected Sub AGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowIndex = 1 Then
        e.Row.Cells(3).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Working fine.

Comment: Hi i have one follow up question..While making visible =false..My Gridview border for particular cell vanishes.Here for Name A  my edit is invisible also border for particular cell  also  vanishes ..

Comment: I think that is because the html for the cell is not rendered at all, once the GridViewCell's Visible property is set to false. Can you try changing the line `e.Row.Cells(3).Visible = False` to `e.Row.Cells(3).Controls.Cast(Of Control)().First().Visible = False` and then say if it helped?

Comment: Thanks for the solution..I have  done like e.Row.Cells(3).Text =string.empty which works perfectly..