# Error when I tried to hide the delete button on the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the error below when I tried to hide the delete button from the gridview  when the user is not admin.
***"Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object***"

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ClinicalFollowUpID"
  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"                            
  AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" PageSize="5"
OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting">
<Columns>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ClinicalFollowUpID"
      OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing"   OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
  OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
   <ItemTemplate >
     <asp:Label ID="lblClinicalFollowUpID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClinicalFollowUpID") %>' >
    </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MBID">
       <ItemTemplate >
  <asp:Label ID="lblMBID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MBID") %>' >
      </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150" HeaderText="Click to Edit">
        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
         </asp:CommandField>
        </Columns>
```

C# Code

```
  protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        lbltype.Text = Session["Type"].ToString();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if (lbltype.Text != "admin")
            {

               LinkButton lnkedit = (LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("lnkedit");
                lnkedit.Visible = false;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Please check your gridview HTML and see if there is any linkbutton named "lnkedit".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Why not add an ItemTemplate so you can have more control
[how-to-disable-a-control-in-command-field-control-in-gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187879/how-to-disable-a-control-in-command-field-control-in-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the link button using FindControl unless you define the template manually after turning off the *AutoGenerateEditButton* property of the grid view.

Try the following to find the edit link button and hide it (assuming the last column corresponds to the command field):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     if (lbltype.Text != "admin")
       {
         LinkButton deleteLink = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[2];
         if(deleteLink != null && deleteLink.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
           {
              deleteLink.Visible = false;
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ashin thanks for your help the code is working but instead of hiding the delete button it's hiding the edit button any help how to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer..just have to get the second item in the control array

Comment: sorry, i have updated the answer yet again..you need to use the following code: LinkButton deleteLink = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[2];
         deleteLink.Visible = false;

Comment: Hi Ashin Thanks for you advise.The code now hide the delete button but the issue I have now is when you click on Edit button instead of showing the Update and  Cancel button is only the update button that is visible therefore a user cannot cancel an update if they want to. Any help how to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: please check the updated answer..That should fix the issue. I will provide a better way to tackle this..just give me some time

Comment: Thanks Ashin Worked great. I will accept the answer. If you have a better solution please feel free to add

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("Link");
        btnEdit.Visible = false;
```

or

```
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        {
         var editBtn=   e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[2] as Button;
         editBtn.Visible = false;

        }
```